# VBA Workshhet Change - Limit the Change Just For Specific Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a trigger that I want to use in certain worksheet - just inside 2 specific columns. But whan I enter a value inside another range it triggers the Private Sub of that worksheet.
I want it would start to work just whan I cange value within columns E or H.
Is someone knows how to do it right?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim LR As Long
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

'WE WANT TO KEEP THE TARGET COLUMNS BETWEEN 0% TO 100%
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng1 = Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(2, "E"), Cells(LR, "E")))

On Error GoTo 1
If Target.Value < 0 Or Target.Value > 1 Then
    MsgBox "bla bla bla", vbCritical + vbMsgBoxRtlReading + vbMsgBoxRight, "error"
    Target.Value = 0
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo 1
Set rng2 = Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(2, "H"), Cells(LR, "H")))
If Target.Value < 0 Or Target.Value > 1 Then
    MsgBox "bla bla bla", vbCritical + vbMsgBoxRtlReading + vbMsgBoxRight, "error"
    Target.Value = 0
    Exit Sub
End If


1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to check if `Target` intersects with your desired range. I would Union the two columns together in this check.

As cryptically stated by DisplayName, since `Target` can contain more than one cell, you should check each cell in target individually. Alternatively, if your intention for `Target` was to always have one cell, then you can avoid the `For...Each` statement altogether and use this check: `If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` to not run the procedure when more than 1 cell is changed.

I also added another intersect target, `Me.Rows("2:" & rows.count)` to avoid updating any headers you may have. If your data does not contain headers, then you can remove this range from `Intersect()`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo safeExit

    Dim rngIntersect As Range
    Set rngIntersect = Intersect(Target, Union(Me.Columns("E"), Me.Columns("H")), _
                                                        Me.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count))

    If Not rngIntersect Is Nothing Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False

        Dim cel As Range
        For Each cel In rngIntersect
            If cel.Value < 0 Or cel.Value > 1 Then
                MsgBox "bla bla bla", vbCritical + vbMsgBoxRtlReading + vbMsgBoxRight, _
                                                                                "error"
                cel.Value = 0
            End If
        Next cel

    End If

safeExit:

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

As a side note, when you are using the same exact range more than once, it's not a bad idea to go ahead and set that range to a variable. So, we use `rngIntersect` twice in this code, so this prevents us from having to issue multiple calls to the `Intersect()` and `Union()` functions. On top of that, you run into less debugging headaches when you only have to update the range in one place rather than multiple times in your code.

Comment: 1) to avoid (possible) endless looping you'd better add proper `Application.EnableEvents` handling. 2) `rng1` seems useless

Comment: Thanks. I didn't really fully inspect his code as I should have. I agree that `rng1` does look redundant, but I am reluctant to remove it in the event OP provided a reduced version of the code and actually has a use for it. But I did update per your suggestion on the events

Comment: Although accepted, your answer still leaves with some relevant not handled issues, which @user10794223 correctly addresses. You may want to enhance your answer for Rafael and future readers (and avoid being yourself the _Target_ of some `SO_DownVoteNotPerfectAnswer()` event handler I see running over here by some mostly frustrated users)

Answer (score 1):

The intersect can check if any of the cells in Target (yes, Target can be more than a single cell) intersect with the Union of columns E and H.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' this next line could also be,
    'If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:E, H:H")) Is Nothing Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Union(Range("E:E"), Range("H:H"))) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bye_bye
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim t As Range
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Union(Range("E:E"), Range("H:H")))
            If (t.Value2 < 0 Or t.Value2 > 1) And t.Row > 1 Then
                MsgBox "bla bla bla", vbCritical + vbMsgBoxRtlReading + vbMsgBoxRight, "error"
                t = 0
            End If
        Next t
    End If

bye_bye:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Since you (properly) changed OP's code in some relevant way, you may want to add some notes about what/why you added and removed